# Is the Ryzen 2 7 PRO 3700U less power efficient than 8th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-8565U?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, battery-life, intel-core-i7, amd-ryzen

[Lenovo x395 (Ryzen variant)](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x/X395/p/22TP2TXX395) says

> Up to **14.5 hours** 48Wh (Based on testing with MobileMark 2014. Battery life varies significantly with settings, usage, and other factors.)

[Lenovo x390 (Intel variant)](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x/X390/p/22TP2TX3900), says

> Up to **17.6 hours** with 48 Whr battery. Based on testing with MobileMark 2014. Battery life varies significantly with settings, usage, and other factors.

I'm wondering about this benchmark. There are three models of the Ryzen II offered in the x395,

- AMD Ryzen™ 3 PRO 3300U Processor (2.1GHz, up to 3.5GHz Max Boost, 4 cores, 4MB Cache)
- AMD Ryzen™ 5 PRO 3500U Processor (2.1GHz, up to 3.7GHz Max Boost, 4 cores, 4MB Cache)
- AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 3700U Processor (2.3GHz, up to 4.0GHz Max Boost, 4 cores, 4MB Cache)

And, there are two models of the Intel offered in the x390,

- 8th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-8265U Processor (1.60GHz, up to 3.90GHz with Turbo Boost, 4 Cores, 6MB Cache)
- 8th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-8565U Processor (1.80GHz, up to 4.60GHz with Turbo Boost, 4 Cores, 8MB Cache)

They don't benchmark these independently but I'm really only interested in the comparison between the i7 and Ryzen™ 7 variants.

Comment: I'll be specific. =)

Comment: @Ramhound I wasn't aware they were even offering the two lower end Ryzens. My bad. I did say i7 in the question though.

Comment: I guess when they say "up to", that test is made with the processor that is the least power hungry. Then I would say yes the Intel one is less power hungry, if you trust the benchmark. You should ask Lenovo about these benchmarks. No one else knows better.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen I'm less concerned with what Lenovo says than the objective power consumption of the i7 and Ryzen 3700U

Comment: @Ramhound yep;.

Comment: The mobilemark benchmark does not show efficiency of a processor. It shows how long battery lasts. You can have an old atom processor beating both of these processors.  What you need is a benchmark application which will run from 100% battery to 0% and count amount of operations made in this duration. Only this can tell efficiency of processors.

Answer (score 4):

For a processor to deliver long battery life, it needs to be efficient both at idle and under various loads.

It goes without saying that the processor's performance relative to the amount of power it consumes—its [performance per watt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_per_watt)—greatly impacts the system's battery life. However, because most consumer workloads only involve brief bursts of activity, the processor's idle power consumption is generally the most important factor.

Additionally, a processor that can quickly burst to a high power level in order to complete a task faster before dropping back to idle may use less total energy than a processor that takes longer to perform the same task even if its peak power draw is lower. *Race to sleep* takes advantage of this principle: the faster the processor completes an operation, the less time it's under load, and the more time it's in the power-saving idle state.

It's true that AMD's mobile processors have dramatically improved power efficiency in recent years<sup>1</sup>. In fact, the fastest Ryzen Mobile processors have *higher performance per watt* under heavy loads in power-constrained conditions than competing Intel processors (hence [AMD's claim of "world's fastest processor for ultrathin laptops"](https://www.amd.com/en/products/ryzen-processors-laptop)). However, Intel processors have better power efficiency at idle and in light loads. This ultimately outweighs the AMD processor's performance-per-watt advantage, resulting in longer battery life on the Intel-powered machine.

---

<sup>1</sup>The Ryzen Mobile 2000 series processors (codenamed *Raven Ridge*) had unusually high idle power consumption, resulting in poor battery life. As the owner of a laptop equipped with a Ryzen 7 2700U processor, I can personally attest to this. AMD significantly improved idle power in the 3000 series (codenamed *Picasso*), but it's not quite enough to completely close the gap.